# Updating multiple MySql entrys

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on creating an internal site for our company. I haven't had many issues until now. I have been able to retrieve and insert data into my database, but now for some reason when I try to UPDATE an entry, the database can't be selected for some strange reason. I've attached a copy of my code thus far. I don't know what I am missing. Thank you!

This is my code for looking up the information in the database:

```
   <?php
session_start();

$transport = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw", "db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>

<?php

$raw_date = $_POST['appt_date'];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($raw_date));


if ($raw_date == '') {
    echo "Please go back and pick a date";
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date = '".$date."' ORDER BY appttime";

$result = mysqli_query($transport, $sql);

$i=0;

echo "<h2 align='center'>Schedule for $raw_date</h2>";

echo "<table border='2' style='width: 100%; margin: auto; border-width: 1px'><tr><th>Resident Name</th><th>APT #</th><th>Appt. Time</th><th>Location Phone</th><th>Location Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>Zip</th><th>Bus or Car</th><th>Escort Name</th><th>Transfer</th><th>Comments</th><th>Dparting Times</th></tr>";

echo "<form name='update_times' method='post' action='depart.php'>\n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value=" . $row['id'] . "";
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['r_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['room'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . date("g:i A", strtotime($row['appttime'])) . "</td>";  
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['apptphone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['l_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['zip'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['buscar'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['escort_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['transfer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='out[$i]' style='width: 70px' type='text' value='" . date("g:i A", strtotime($row['depart'])) . "' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  ++$i;  
  }

echo "<input type='submit' value='Set Depart Times'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";

$_SESSION['sessionVar'] = $raw_date;


?>
```

This is the update code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$transport = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db_name');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>

<?php
$size = count($_POST['out']);

$i=0;
while ($i < $size)
{
    $departing = $_POST['out'][$i];
    $departing = date("H:i:s:u",strtotime($departing));
    $id = $_POST['id'][$i];

    $sql = "UPDATE transport.appointments SET depart = $departing WHERE id = $id";
    mysqli_query($transport, $sql) or die ("Error in query: $sql");
    echo "Depart times updated!";
    ++$i;

}

mysql_close($transport);
?>
```

For some reason the update code doesn't want to select my database. Thank you again!

Comment: Where's your `mysqli_select_db()`?

Comment: @AnPhan you don't need one, it's the fourth parameter of `mysqli_connect`

Comment: Shouldn't this line `mysqli_query($sql1, $sql)` actually be `mysqli_query($transport, $sql)`? Where does `$sql1` come from?

Comment: @FDL Right, silly me...

Comment: rats, that's something I was playing with. I changed it back to $transport, $sql. I was just trying some things out.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL UPDATE syntax is:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,... WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

It looks like you've tried to reference your database and your table in the UPDATE query: `transport.appointments`. I might be wrong, but I can't find anything on the internet saying that is valid syntax.

Try just referencing the table:

```
$sql = "UPDATE appointments SET depart = $departing WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: I've tried it with and without transport.appointments. If I put ' around the $departing, it comes up with this error: Error: Unknown column 'tr' in 'where clause' I've also tried to do it without the ' around $departing and it cuts off the first number of the time.

Comment: You need to have single quotes around $departing. What's the value of `$id`? Also, you should validate $_POST data before using it in a database query as otherwise someone can code inject.

Comment: The value of $id changes depending on which entry they're updating. It shows up with the correct ID for the column. I tried with single quotes and I get that error: Error: Unknown column 'tr' in 'where clause'

Comment: Before you run the query, echo `$sql`, and share it here. If the error is about the WHERE clause the problem is most likely with the `$id` variable.

Comment: UPDATE appointments SET depart = '05:44:00' WHERE id = 1 is what I get.

Comment: Are you sure that's the query that's giving you the error? That is syntactically correct. What does `print_r($_POST['id'])` output?

Comment: I get this: Array ( [0] => 1 4 8 3 5 10 6 7 9 which is all of the ID's that are in my table.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it. I have no idea what those values are. My table has values from 1 to 10 and the entries I'm trying to change are ID 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: ugh, I figured it out... apparently in my main code I forgot to > the HTML :(. Thank you for all you guys' help!